# Reverse list item values

Tags: python

I want to reverse all the values in my list. My list is composed of 0, 1, 2 and 3 (for example [0,2,2,3,1,3,2]) and I want to reverse the values of the items (change all the 0 to 3, all the 1 to, all the 2 to 1 and all the 3 to 0 => [3,1,1,0,2,0,1]).

Is it possible in python ?

I tried to use list comprehensions without any success.

```py
li=[0,2,2,3,1,3,2]
print(list(reversed(li)))
```

What I have: [0,2,2,3,1,3,2]
What I want: [3,1,1,0,2,0,1]

Comment: `reversed` is to change the *order*, not replace the values. You mentioned you tried a list comprehension - `[3 - x for x in li]`?

Comment: "I tried to use list comprehensions without any success." What did that code look like? What happened when you tried it, and how was it wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Use a `map` and subtract each value with the maximum value in the list `l`:

```
>>> l = [0,2,2,3,1,3,2]
>>> list(map(max(l).__sub__, l))
[3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
>>>
```

Or use a list comprehension:

```
>>> [max(l) - i for i in l]
[3, 1, 1, 0, 2, 0, 1]
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `reversed` function will reverse the *order* of the list rather than the values in the list itself. There are a few ways you could do what you're trying to do using `map` to apply a function to every element of the list. Here is one that would work for your specific example:

```
list(map(lambda x: abs(x-3), li)
```